# Editing a stream - Racket

Tags: stream, racket

Well, I am trying to get some things in racket, I am currently studying streams. I try to create a function that will edit a stream, for example add a pair of (int, element) in place of each stream's element.

For example initial_stream : <1,2,3, …>
            edited_stream  : <(int . 1) (int . 2) (int . 3) ….. >

I wrote this but it seems to enter an endless loop (with int=>13)

```
(define (stream-add-zero s)
  (cons (cons 13 (car (s))) (stream-add-zero (cdr (s)))))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If by "stream" you mean Racket's lazy stream data structure, this can be done with an application of [stream-map](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=stream-map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-map%29%29).

```
(define initial-stream (in-naturals))
(define edited-stream (stream-map (λ (i) (cons 'int i)) initial-stream))

;; sanity check
(require rackunit)
(check-equal? (stream-ref edited-stream 3) '(int . 3))
```

This is assuming the `int` in your `edited_stream` was a symbol.